# React-Static scroll to top on page change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-static

Is there a way to scroll to the top when the page change with react-static ? I'm using `@reach/router` which is include by default with `react-static`.

I've already tried this :

```js
<Router onChange={window.scrollTo(0,0)}>
   <Routes path="*"/>
</Router>
```

ans this (from this [issue](https://github.com/react-static/react-static/issues/551))

```js
<Router history={history} autoScrollToTop={true}>
   <Routes path="*"/>
</Router>
```

but both did not work.

The last solution was mentionned in the react-static doc but seems to be deprecate since it is not longer in the doc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a new component `Scrolltotop.js`

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useLocation } from '@reach/router'

export default function Scrolltotop () {
  const { pathname } = useLocation()

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0)
  }, [pathname])

  return null
}
```

and import it to `App.js`

```
import Scrolltotop from './components/Scrolltotop'
```

and add it to the App function :

```
function App () {
  return (
    <Root>
      <Scrolltotop/>
      <Router>
        <Routes path="*"/>
      </Router>
    </Root>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try having a component that handles the scroll for you and lives above your app component.

Usage:

```js
import ManageScroll from './ManageScroll';
ReactDOM.render(<Fragment><ManageScroll/><App/></Fragment>, node);
```

ManageScroll.js:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Location } from "@reach/router";

let scrollPositions = {};

class ManageScrollImpl extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    try {
      // session storage will throw for a few reasons
      // - user settings
      // - in-cognito/private browsing
      // - who knows...
      let storage = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("scrollPositions"));
      if (storage) {
        scrollPositions = JSON.parse(storage) || {};
        let { key } = this.props.location;
        if (scrollPositions[key]) {
          window.scrollTo(0, scrollPositions[key]);
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {}

    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.listener);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.listener);
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    const { key } = this.props.location;
    if (!scrollPositions[key]) {
      // never seen this location before
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    } else {
      // seen it
      window.scrollTo(0, scrollPositions[key]);
    }
  }

  listener = () => {
    scrollPositions[this.props.location.key] = window.scrollY;
    try {
      sessionStorage.setItem(
        "scrollPositions",
        JSON.stringify(scrollPositions)
      );
    } catch (e) {}
  };

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

export default () => (
  <Location>
    {({ location }) => <ManageScrollImpl location={location} />}
  </Location>
);
```

check out this gist for further info https://gist.github.com/ryanflorence/39a37a85254159fd7a5ca54027e175dc

hope this helps!

Comment: No.  Never used react-static.  But if it uses reach router under the hood, it's worth a shot to try it out.  This code is from the author of reach router after all.